# How to choose one specific fgure to plot in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

How to choose one specific fgure to plot in Matlab? `hold on` cannot help if I want to choose not last figure. Is it possible to choose specific figure to display information in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Special function [`figure`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/figure.html) is used to *create new* figure graphics objects as well as for *selecting some older, already present figure* as active for imminent plotting. Function `figure` and plotting functions (`plot`, `stem` etc.) return figure handle of currently active figure that could be used later.

Here's an example:

```
fh = figure;  % create new figure and save handle in fh
plot( ... something ... );
...
```

When you want to plot to that figure again you should do:

```
figure(fh);
plot( ... something else ...);
```

Comment: The plotting functions return handles to the children they create, not the figure the plot into.

Comment: @janh Ok, that isn't too precisely stated. You could suggest edit to the answer by *editing* it.